# High Chart Bar Chart, How to Show Date In Series?

Tags: javascript, php, charts, highcharts

I want to Develop a Bar Chart, where in X-axis there will be some data about Line Number. In my Chart i want to show date interval. Assume there will be a start date and an end date. I have done something like this: 
1. My connection page (demo.php) is like that:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("demo_planning", $con);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT alocate_line, sewing_end, sewing_start FROM demo_input");

$category = array();
$category['name'] = 'Line';

$series1 = array();
$series1['name'] = 'Sewing End';

$series2 = array();
$series2['name'] = 'Sewing Start';


while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $category['data'][] = $r['alocate_line'];
    $series1['data'][] = str_replace("-",",",$r['sewing_end']);
    $series2['data'][] = str_replace("-",",",$r['sewing_start']);

}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$category);
array_push($result,$series1);
array_push($result,$series2);



print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

My High chart page is like That:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
        },
        title: {
            text: 'INPUT',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Requests'
            },
                plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 3,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y;
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
         plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                }
            }
        },
        series: []
    }

    $.getJSON("data_demo.php", function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                options.series[0] = json[1];
                options.series[1] = json[2];
     chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: What is the current problem ? what is date format you are getting?   .. would better if can share problem with fiddle link

Comment: How your JSON does look like ?

Comment: 1. The current problem is, for sewing end(as i mention) the bar chart remain blank,  Nothing show at all. I think there will be a problem with date .May be the High Chart api does not support current format of date which is retrieve from DB. @ Nishith Chaturvedi

Comment: In the Highcharts you need to use a timestamps (time in miliseconds).

Comment: hmm.can you give me some example

Comment: Highcharts needs either Epoch time:  http://www.epochconverter.com/ or a Date.UTC object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Comment: If my JSON output is like that, How to show it in High chart barchart: [{"name":"1","data":"[Date.UTC(2015,10,05), 35316 ]"},1,2015,10,05,35316{"name":"2","data":"[Date.UTC(2015,10,11), 50898 ]"},2,2015,10,11,50898,{"name":"2","data":"[Date.UTC(2015,10,04), 35657 ]"},2,2015,10,04,35657,{"name":"2","data":"[Date.UTC(2015,10,03), 80336 ]"},2,2015,10,03,80336,{"name":"2","data":"[Date.UTC(2015,10,02), 11837 ]"},2,2015,10,02,11837,{"name":"3","data":"[Date.UTC(2015,10,09), 1200 ]"},3,2015,10,09,1200] @ Sebastian Bochan

Comment: In the JSON you cannot use functions, you need to use native timestamps or load json and convert dates in preprocessing (before chart init).